# copy files with authentication in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, impersonation

I built a .net core app (2.0) that copy file from one server to another using 
System.io that looks like this:

```
if (!File.Exists(DestinationFullPath)) //copy only if file not exists
{
    try {
        runner.WriteLogs(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
            LogLevel.Information, "Start copying file from :{0} to {1} ",
            pFromPath, pToPath);

        File.Copy(file, DestinationFullPath);

        runner.WriteLogs(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
            LogLevel.Information, "{0} copied to {1}",
            file, pToPath);

    } catch (Exception) {
        runner.WriteLogs(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
            LogLevel.Critical, "Error in copying {0} to {1}",
            file, pToPath);
    }
}
```

The problem with it that when I run in on Linux containers, it wants a specific user with permission.

I am aware of Impersonation but not in core 2.0, does anyone know a way to perform it?

Something along the lines of:

```
var Impersonation = new XXX();
Impersonation.username = "XXX";
Impersonation.Password = "XXX";
Impersonation.Domain = "XXX";

Using(Impersonation) {

    //copy only if file not exists
    if (!File.Exists(DestinationFullPath)) {
        try {
            runner.WriteLogs(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
                LogLevel.Information, "Start copying file from :{0} to {1} ",
                pFromPath, pToPath);

            File.Copy(file, DestinationFullPath);

            runner.WriteLogs(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
                LogLevel.Information, "{0} copied to {1}",
                file, pToPath);

        } catch (Exception) {
            runner.WriteLogs(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString(),
                LogLevel.Critical, "Error in copying {0} to {1}",
                file, pToPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also have this question. Did you manage to accomplish the impersonation?

Comment: Unfortunately , no.